# What is the point of using Item Decorations in RecyclerView VS editing the individual inflated layouts?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Basically what the title asks, what is the point of having item decorations in recycler views if you can achieve the same effect by editing the layout you are inflating in the recycler view.

Comment: The main reason for them is code organization and offloading some of the load from the recycler item view inflater to the OS level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you cannot *always* "achieve the same effect by editing the layout you are inflating in the recycler view" very easily.

This is particularly true if you want `ListView`-style dividers that go *between* entries (say, in a vertical list). In that case, not every item has a divider -- either the first or the last does not. For simple cases, you could still handle that within the layouts themselves, by hiding a divider in the layout when it's the item that should not have a divider. However, if you:

- allow users to reorder the items, or
- you use something like `SortedList` to keep items in a sorted order, or
- you are dynamically adding and removing items

then trying to make sure that the dividers are handled correctly is a pain, because which items get and do not get the divider keep shifting.

The item decoration approach keeps the logic for drawing decorations independent of the items themselves, so changes in the mix of items does not affect the decoration process. It also makes it easier to:

- implement standard item decoration patterns in a library
- dynamically change decoration patterns on the fly, such as based on user preferences

Not every `RecyclerView` will use item decorations. In particular, those using `CardView` for the top-level layout for items probably skip item decorations, as the `CardView` itself provides visual distinction and separation between items.

So, you do not *have* to use the item decoration approach, but it is available for cases where it simplifies how you set up your UI.

Comment: For the divider effect all I would have to do is add bottom margin to the parent layout of the layout I am inflating in the item view, or I can even add a view at the bottom with height and background color of my desire. So in this way I dont have to check any conditions, because if i dont want the topmost item to not have a divider showing at the top, i just have to not put a divider view at the top of my item view layout. But I do understand the motivation for keeping the global item separation logic separate from the individual item inflation and rendering logic

Comment: @Bhargav: "add bottom margin to the parent layout of the layout I am inflating in the item view" -- while that provides visual separation, that does not draw a divider line. It also adds unnecessary extra space at the top or bottom. "I can even add a view at the bottom with height and background color of my desire" -- except that you will have an extra view at the top or bottom. Usually, the objective of a decoration is to go *between* items, meaning if there are five items shown, there are only four decorations. Handling that is tricky, as I outlined in my answer.

Comment: @Bhargav: "if i dont want the topmost item to not have a divider showing at the top, i just have to not put a divider view at the top of my item view layout" -- however, what the top item is varies, if the contents of the `RecyclerView` changes, as I outlined in my answer.

Comment: Yes if we wanted dividers only between items then what you say is correct

Comment: Thanks for answering now I understand :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, handling stuff like dividers in the item layouts IS possible, but can be tricky and results in additional, useless code. The `Decorator`, on the other hand, allows you to draw them easily, right into the `Canvas`. You can also draw other things, like badges, highlights etc.

However, this is not the main reason. The true reason is the fact that `RecyclerView` **is not and should not be seen as a "cooler `ListView`"**. It is so much more! :-)

Imagine you want to draw a Zuma-like structure of star-shaped items. You can do it easily with a `RecyclerView` and a custom `LayoutManager`. And if you want to add dividers to such a layout, it will be easier to draw directly onto the canvas, will it not?

`RecyclerView` is, well, a recycler view, an abstract, top-level implementation for all recycling `Views` (so `ListView`, `GridView`, `StarShapedZumaSnakeView` etc.) :-)

Comment: So like you say if I had a listview type of implementation of recycler view with a vertical linear layout manager and what not would it be more efficient to set margin to the inflating layout or use a item decoration to achieve the effect of item divider

Comment: For a simple list it would be easier, yes, but you would need some code to hide the divider on the last item etc. The decorator can handle it all in one place and as for efficiency, it is actually better for Decorator, as you replace XML parsing with on-canvas drawing (which has to be done anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You are Only considering the simple case of adding just a divider. When you have complex groupings it becomes easier to offload the work to the ItemDecorator.

and You cant **always** achieve the same effect by editing the layout.It maybe because of  design constraints or some other reason.

An ItemDecoration allows the application to add a special drawing and layout offset to specific item views from the adapter's data set. This can be useful for drawing dividers between items, highlights, visual grouping boundaries and more.

Comment: That does not really answer the question, of why decorators versus putting those effects in the individual item views themselves.

Comment: @CommonsWare but wouldnt it be easier to use decorator when there needs to be multiple grouping in the same recyclerview.